# error in getting a remote file in shell script

Tags: unix, shell, ssh, remote-access, scp

I have this script that is doing a scp onto 4 servers and getting the file on the calling server , but when I run it I get the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `then'
line 16: `if[[ $line = $texts ]] ; then
```

The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
servers=("root@67.215.227.233" "root@57.245.127.134" "root@67.215.127.135" "root@116.244.128.153")
tlen=${#servers[@]}
count=o
total=0
texts="Untar done you can upload new .tar file"
for(( i=0; i<${tlen}; i++ ));
    do
    echo "in"
    scp ${servers[$i]}:/usr/site/html/test/test.txt /mnt/backups/updateimage
    cat test.txt ; while read line
    do
    echo "in"
    let count++
    echo "$line"
    if[[ $line = $texts ]] ; then 
    echo "true" 
    let total++ 
    else echo "false" 
    fi
   done < test.txt
done
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a space between `if` and `[[`

**EDIT**

I've just ran this test and it properly evaluates to false

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

texts="Untar done you can upload new .tar file"
line="foo"

if [[ $line = $texts ]] ; then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

I suspect your problem is elsewhere

Comment: I would think a space between `for` and `((` would be required too. bash syntax is much more sensitive to whitespace than C-like languages.

Comment: @glenn. Good spotting. Actually, the space is also missing between third and fourth servers, meaning `servers` array only contains 3 elements, and the third one is VERY invalid.

Comment: @Alexander 
Thanks guys for the suggestion and I have changed my code accordingly , but I see that my If condition is yielding true even when there is no match .. any ideas as to why is it doing like that ?

I have the following code: 
texts="Untar done you can upload new .tar file"
while read line
do
#echo "in"
let count++
echo "$line"
if [[ "$line" == "$texts" ]] ; then 
echo "true"
let total++ 
else echo "false" 
fi

Comment: @Alexander: yes it works fine , the problem I suspect is when I do a scp from the 4 servers I maynot overwrite the local copy of the file. I made a little change in the contents of the file on 1st server so as I can get a false after comparison but it still goes in to say the strings are same. I don't know where the problem is.
thanks !

Comment: @Jassi. You copy `test.txt` to `/mnt/backups/updateimage`, but reading `test.txt` from local directory, of course it stays the same.

Comment: @Alexander. Yeah I got the problem fixed. It was the path issue which I figured out before but then all the files had a carriage return to the next line and the file on the first server didn't have that. so my while read didn't work... now everything is working!
thanks

Comment: @Jassi. Glad to be of help.  You'll never regret mastering shell scripts!